# Better Understanding Big O and Big Theta with a divide and conquer search

Tags: computer-science, big-o

> A divide and conquer algorithm takes an array of size n as input and
>   makes two recursive calls on arrays of size n/2. Then, after an
>   additional O(n) work, it produces an output. The running time should
>   be:
>
> a) Θ(n)
>   b) Θ(n log n)
>   c) Θ(n^(log₂(3)))
>   d) Θ(n²)

I'm trying to review for an exam and this is a question off the review. Intuitively I want to say b, because I know divide and conquer algorithms run at O(n log n), but the fact the answers are in Big Theta completely throws me off. Why would the question refer to "an additional O(n) work" then supply answers in Big Theta?

Any help appreciated. I'm just trying to understand this better.

Comment: Busted problem. Depending on the actual function standing in for O(n), the answer could be Theta(n) or Theta(n log n) (or, with a bit of a stretch, neither).

Comment: Could you provide how you came to the conclusion it could be either Theta(n) or Theta(n log n) ?

Comment: Both 1 and n are O(n). Use the Master Theorem.